# Model comparison from the results from the mixed() function of the afex package

Tags: r, lme4, model-comparison

I am new to R and lmer. We have a project examining the effects of mimicking others’ voice (mimicry vs nonmimicry, a between-subjects fixed effect) , modality (reading vs listening, a within-subjects effect), valence (positive vs negative; a within-subjects effect), and category (personality vs appearance,a within-subjects effect )  on the imitator’s judgement of some comments (Pleasantness, continuous, 1-7). We constructed a theoretically full mixed-effects model and wanted to decided the best model. Based on the recommendations of a paper, we tried to use the mixed () function from the afex package to conduct a likelihood-ratio test. The following is the code and summary of the model estimation. Now we are not very sure about how to interpret the result. The summary showed that  in Row “10” and “11”, the p values are significant, but in Row “8” are “9”, the p value are not significant. In this case, how can we decide what terms should a best model include? Do we simply include those terms whose p values are significant and drop those whose are not?

Your help and advice will be much appreciated!

```
Fitting 16 (g)lmer() models:
[................]
Mixed Model Anova Table (Type 3 tests, LRT-method)

Model: Pleasantness ~ mimicry * modality * valence * category + (1 | 
Model:     Subject)
Data: df
Df full model: 18
                              Effect df       Chisq p.value
1                            mimicry  1      6.44 *    .011
2                           modality  1   19.00 ***   <.001
3                            valence  1 4493.93 ***   <.001
4                           category  1     7.86 **    .005
5                   mimicry:modality  1      3.74 +    .053
6                    mimicry:valence  1        0.37    .542
7                   modality:valence  1      4.23 *    .040
8                   mimicry:category  1        2.22    .136
9                  modality:category  1        0.68    .409
10                  valence:category  1      5.53 *    .019
11          mimicry:modality:valence  1      4.12 *    .042
12         mimicry:modality:category  1        0.09    .770
13          mimicry:valence:category  1        0.53    .465
14         modality:valence:category  1        0.24    .622
15 mimicry:modality:valence:category  1        0.63    .428
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about model fitting or interpreting results from statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am very new to coding and model fitting. Sorry for misplacing the post.